# How can I change the css properties of a google visualization table and it columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization, data-visualization

How can I change the css properties of a google visualization table and it's columns? I've read on the dev website how to adjust individual **cell** and **row** background, text color, etc., but there is no information on how to adjust **column** or **table** boarder, color, padding, etc.

This code is from the google [dev website](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples#custom_table_example) and the example is also found in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790553/styling-google-charts-table/24782315#24782315)

CSS Properties:

```
<style>
.orange-background {
   background-color: orange;
  }

 .orchid-background {
  background-color: orchid;
 }

.beige-background {
 background-color: beige;
  }
</style>
```

Table Code:

```
var cssClassNames = {
'headerRow': 'italic-darkblue-font large-font bold-font',
'tableRow': '',
'oddTableRow': 'beige-background',
'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background large-font',
'hoverTableRow': '',
'headerCell': 'gold-border',
'tableCell': '',
'rowNumberCell': 'underline-blue-font'};

var options = {'showRowNumber': true, 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames};

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

//... add data here ...

var table = new google.visualization.Table(container);
table.draw(data, options);
```

There are no classname properties that refer to the **columns** or **table** as a whole. My priority is to eliminate the table boarder on the outside and adjust the column width, making the entire table smaller.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Table has the class `google-visualization-table-table` that you can style.  There are no column elements to style, so you have to set the width of cells in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i did a google search on '`google-visualization-table-table`' and came across this [page](https://code.google.com/p/browserscope/source/browse/trunk/static/goog_table.css?r=765).

It had multiple examples of table css properties, ie.:

```
.google-visualization-table-table {
  font-family: arial, helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

thanks for the help [asgallant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613559/asgallant)!